# Intersection of all non normal.subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group and collect all the non-normal subgroups of $G$. Then what will the intersection of all those be? Normal?

The examples that I took,  like $S_3, S_4, D_4$, every time the trivial subgroup is coming and that is normal.

> But is there any theorem to support this?

Comment: It will definitely be normal, as being non normal is preserved by conjugation.

Comment: I think you want to read http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869366900184